# xpath filter on calculated value

Tags: xml, xpath, calculated-columns

I am using Xpath to filter a product feed that is uploaded into my website every day.

The feed is a simple CSV with a list of products. To load only the products that have a discount I am using the following Xpath expression:

```
/node[price_from != price]
```

However, what I really need to do is filter on the products that have a discount of more than 30%. From what I can find it seems that Xpath can handle calculations, but I have not been able to find an example where a filter was made based on a calculated value.

Basically I am looking for an expression that would do this (this doesn't work though):

```
/node[(price / price_from) < 0,7]
```

Does anybody know if the above type of expression is at all possible? I can only use Xpath to filter and I have no control over the feed, so I cannot add a column before that contains the discount percentage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find documentation for operators [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_operators.asp)

Also, you need to make sure attribute or node value are number (you can use `number()` function to cast)

I believe something like this would work

```
/node[(price div price_from) < 0,7]
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. I didn't have to cast to number, but I had to change the 0,7 to 0.7 also because of a different number notation.

Answer (score 1):

Operator for division in xpath is `div`, not `/` (remember that `/` already used for path separator in xpath). So you should be able to do the following :

```
/node[(price div price_from) < 0.7]
```

From [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) xpath 1.0 spec :

> The `div` operator performs floating-point division according to IEEE 754.
>
> The `mod` operator returns the remainder from a truncating division.

Comment: This is the more useful answer and should be the accepted one.